# Why does ASP.NET MVC client side validation fail when 'Title' property exists on view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, client-side-validation

The question already points out half of the problem, which is what appears to be an extremely onerous framework bug, namely: When your view model has a `Title` property, binding to that property makes client-side validation fail to work:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
```

The resultant `input` tag contains no validation attributes in it, and it also seems to make the rest of client-side validation fail for other properties as well (I'm 90% sure on that).

Questions:

1. Has someone else ever documented this long-running bug?
2. What is going on here? Importantly, does this only happen when some other extra condition is true? I have a feeling the framework is confusing `ViewBag.Title` with your own view-model's `Title` property.
3. What should one do to mitigate this problem?

Short of having those answers, simply knowing this may be one of the reasons client-side validation is failing is a victory, in my case, it just stole a day and a half of my time, until I narrowed things down to this singular `Title` property. But would love to hear answers to particularly the first two questions above. As for #3)

To mitigate the problem, one solution is to just not use that property, name the property e.g. `Title2`. And if using a mapper, you could still add a `Title` property which gets and sets from this auxilliary `Title2` field, which worked for me, e.g.:

```
public string Title { get => Title2; set { Title2 = value; } }
```

--- Edit ---

Following is a minimal example. I do not have the time to make a complete project, or to reproduce everything. There is of course the possibility some of the setup in the large project I am working in (full-framework MVC 5.2.6) does something which ends up causing this, I don't know. But this is better than nothing. If you bind to `Title`, it fails, bind to `Title2`, it works:

#### View model `FooVM`:

```
public class FooVM
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Title2 { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    // fix with this: public string Title { get => Title2; set { Title2 = value; } }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100_000_000)]
    [Required]
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public int OrgId { get; set; }

}
```

#### View

```
@model FooVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Foo!";
    string msg = ViewBag.Message ?? "";
    // you can test it out directly here if you want:
    //string str2 = Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title).ToHtmlString();
}

<div class="pagetile">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">

            <h2>Yo dog, why you not workin'?</h2>
            <p> @msg.ToHtmlString() </p>

            @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                @Html.ValidationSummary()

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FooId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrgId)

                <div>
                    Title:
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)  @*change to Title2 and it works*@

                    @* 
you can do this manually as well, both helpers fail to produce the validation tags on the generated input element:
@Html.TextBox("Title", "", null, null)
*@

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) @*this part is always fine*@               
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
public class FooController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Foo() 
    {
        return View(new FooVM());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(FooVM vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            ViewBag.Message = $"Not valid!";
            return View(vm);
        }

        ViewBag.Message = "Cool beans";
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

When bound to `Title`, it generates this html:
`<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="">`

[image]

Bound to `Title2` generates this:
`<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Title2 must be a string with a maximum length of 64." data-val-length-max="64" data-val-required="The Title2 field is required." id="Title2" name="Title2" type="text" value="">`

Comment: What kind of client-side validation are you using?

Comment: I should have said that, thanks: The framework provided validation, which is typically included in the framework MVC as nuget packages (`jquery.validate.js`, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`). 

I don't think the problem is on that end though (a bug in the javascript validation logic), because at write time of the html, as I stated: "The resultant input tag contains no validation attributes in it." I.e. tags like `data-val="true"` and `data-val-required="..."` are simply missing, as well as the `aria` ones.

Comment: The input tag does for me. Which version of MVC do you use? Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I have had numerous issues with the unobtrusive validation JS system. I generally setup my razor to use HTML5 validation, then in-model validation on the server-side.

To test whether the Title in the object is the problem or if it is the JS, remove the JS from your frontend, then submit your model to the controller and see what is passed.

Comment: Oh hang on, do you just mean that it is just none of the validation parameters are on the input tag? In that case I suspect it would be the Razor models that deal with the unobtrusive etc. getting confused as you could be referencing the Title viewbag component as you surmised.

Comment: @Slipoch interesting, what do you mean about using HTML5 validation, as opposed to the unobtrusive validation?
- "To test whether the Title in the object is the problem or if it is the JS, remove the JS from your frontend" - Like I said, it's clearly not a JS problem this time, because the input tag doesn't even output the needed validation attributes. I have a feeling as soon as it hits a `Title` property it conflicts with something and suddenly crashes (not crashes: all following validation fails to write).

Comment: Yeah sorry, realised that after I posted then added the comment above.

I made a bit of razor code in one of my websites that uses reflection to get all the object parameters and auto-create the form from it, including help buttons, I use the html5 flags like <input type="text" required />

I will also occasionally use AJAX to hit a server controller for form/object validation on the client-side.

If you want to see the page I use the above code on, it is here: https://nuclearfruitsalad.com/websites/details/request-quote/

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for testing this, which it seems you did, appreciated. I'm a huge fan of minimal examples, by the way. Problem is, to do a full (complete) and verifiable example project would take some time, which I don't have unfortunately, I'm already quite behind after this problem burned me. I can guarantee you this: In my view-model, when I made an auxiliary `Title2` property and bound to that instead, it immediately fixed the problem. I tested again and went back to binding to `Title`, problem re-appears, I go back to `Title2`, it fixes.

Comment: Perhaps your model inherits from another model which also contains a Title property, or whatever? Creating a new MVC 5.2 project with a model with an annotated Title property outputs the appropriate data-val attributes for me.

Comment: Hmm, he's using Unob Validation, then the problem is not with it or with the MVC model.

What other JS libraries do you have going on there? As above, does the model inherit from another? Can you please post your model code?

Comment: Thanks for that extra bit @CodeCaster, I'm sorry to not have a full example, and thus keeping you guessing on different things. My viewmodel in the end was extremely simple, speaking of minimal examples, 5 simple properties, strings and ints only.

Curious, in your example, did you set `ViewBag.Title`? There appears to be some extra factor, since it's working for you.

Comment: Are you using the viewbag for anything?

Comment: Can you press Ctrl+U (View Source) and inspect the generated HTML as opposed to the updated DOM?

Comment: Yep, it's the same (no validation attributes). Furthermore, you can generate the html string directly in the View while debugging, and see the same result (see commented out line at top of the razor page above: `//string str2 = Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title).ToHtmlString();`).